In how many different ways may I paint a map with $x$ colors available? Two resolutions with two different results.
I have a map with four regions:



A
B




C
D



each region is painted with one of $x$ colors and can't be painted with the same color as adjacent regions.
In how many ways can the map be painted?
I've thought of two ways of solving this:

consider $x$ options for A, $x-1$ for B, $x-1$ for D and $x-2$ for C (going around clockwise) which gives us:

$$x(x-1)(x-1)(x-2) = x(x-1)(x^2-3x+2)$$

consider $x$ options for A and then splitting in two cases


B and C are the same and D can't be the same color as B and C: $(x-1)\times 1 \times (x-1)$
B and C are different and D can't be the same color as B and C: $(x-1)(x-2)(x-2)$

This time I get:
$$x(x-1)\left((x-1)+(x-2)^2\right) = x(x-1)(x^2-3x+3)$$
My questions are which of these is correct? Why is the other one wrong?

Does that picture indicate the borders?  So $A$ shares a border with $B$ and with $C$, though not with $D$?

Assuming it does, I don't understand your first method.  Seems that one would also break into cases, according to whether $A=D$ or not.  Second method looks good.

As a suggestion:  Suppose $x=2$.   That case is easy to check by hand and you can compare the result to your formulas.  Eliminates one of them immediately.

@lulu yes, the table is supposed to illustrate the map.

You’re coloring the (possibly labeled) graph $C_4$. You can break the problem down into colorings that use 2, 3, and 4 colors, respectively
